# ActiveWorkbook.conflictresolution xlOtherSessionChanges throws error

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to ask if anyone encounters this problem with excel vba conflictresolution / resolve conflict.

1. I create an excel file called test.xlsm and convert it to a shared workbook over the company network folder.
2. User A opens the file enters "**user A data**" on range **A1** on **sheet1**.
3. User A saves the file.
4. User B opens the file enters "**user B data**" on range **A1** on **sheet1**.
   User B overwrites User A data on A1 sheet1 by clicking on "**Accept All Mine**" on resolve conflict.

What i want is to prevent User B from overwritting User A data by inserting a VBA code on ThisWorkbook.

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeSave(ByVal SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean)
    ActiveWorkbook.ConflictResolution = xlOtherSessionChanges
End Sub
```

However, VBA compiler throws an error. Anyone can advise me on this problem?

```
Method "ConflictResolution' of object'_Workbook' failed
```

VBA conflictresolution reference [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.xlsaveconflictresolution)

[image]

[image]